# form validation laravel 5

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

on my profile update form i have fullname password and confirm password fields . currently my validations are works only for 
empty fields and password mismatch. but how can i add password charactor limits validations as well ? 
password should be min:5 and max 15 charactors.

please advice.

```
public function changePasswordPost()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if (Input::get('password')) {
        if (Input::get('password') !== Input::get('confirm_password')) {

            return Redirect::route('admin-change-password')->with('error', 'Password field is not identical to Confirm Password.');
        }


        $user->update();

        return Redirect::route('admin-change-password')->with('success', 'You have successfully updated login details.');
    }

    return Redirect::route('admin-change-password')->with('error', 'Input Missing');
}
```

Comment: You should use [Laravel's Validation class](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
use Validator;

public function changePasswordPost(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if ($request->get('password')) {
        if (($request->get('password') !== $request->get('confirm_password')) ||
           (Validator::make($request->all(), ['password' => 'min:5|max:15'])->fails())) {

            return redicrect()->route('admin-change-password')->with('error', 'Password field is not identical to Confirm Password.');
        }


        $user->update();

        return redirect()->route('admin-change-password')->with('success', 'You have successfully updated login details.');
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin-change-password')->with('error', 'Input Missing');
}
```

I haven't tested this code but the point is that you need to use Validator class from laravel. Note that I have changed some of the stuff to use laravel-5.1 friendly API.

Note that you can get cleaner code by adding Validation before you do anything. Something like this:

```
public function changePasswordPost(Request $request)
{
    /**
     * This basically captures your password matching
     * and password length cases in a compact way so 
     * you don't need all the if statements.
     */
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),
        ['password' => 'required|min:5|max:15',
         'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password']);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        response()->redirect('admin-change-password')->with('error', 'bad input');
    }

    /**
     * Here you do the rest of the processing like updating the database.
     */
}
```

Comment: Good example, but i would recommend to set a `min:8` and leave out the `max`.